# Content within AJAX Accordion Control appears not to be Initialized at Page_Load()

Tags: controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I do write a label control inside the **content** of  as follows

```
    <ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
    <Panes>
        <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
            <Header> ... </Header>
            <Content> 
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" />
            </Content>
        </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>        
        .
        .
        .
    </Panes>      


    </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```

And in code behind file, I do write as follows

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lblTest.Text = "Hello, World";
 }
```

I get error message while reaching code, Error Message : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Accordion1.FindControl("nothing")
```

in `Page_Init()` where `Accordion1` is your `Accordion` object.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and while meejaydeep's solution works, it feels "hacky".  After some research this appears to be related to the 1.0 version of the AjaxControlToolkit.  This problem appears to be fixed in the 3.5 version of the Toolkit though.  So if you are able to upgrade to that version I would encourage you to do so, otherwise you will need to implement meetjaydeep's fix.

I realize that this thread is several years old, but I figured that this might be worthwhile information for someone in the future.